# Why @font-face font not looks smooth in FF 3.6 but in IE7?

Tags: css

Why @font-face font not looks smooth in FF 3.6 but in IE7?

see this in IE7 , it will look smooth but in FF 3.6 font will look jaaaged.

http://nettuts.s3.amazonaws.com/569_fontface/fontface/index.html

Comment: just wondering - do you have cleartype turned on in IE7 but not in windows?

Answer (score 1):

As scunliffe commented, this definitely sounds like a ClearType issue. Check out this link for more info: http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2006/02/03/524367.aspx

Comment: @Bryan Downing - but i'm having problem in FF not in IE

Comment: I understand, but ClearType is a feature of IE not FF. In other words, your type isn't going to look anti-aliased in FF.

Comment: You mean Font-face font will not look smooth like sIFR.